# Configure authenticate Mechanism in Squirrel SQL Client for DB2

Tags: sql-server, db2, squirrel-sql

I want to configure a DB2 Connection in Squirrel SQL Client and my URL contains `securityMechanism=13` at the end. When I am trying to connect with this URL and Test a connection in Squirrel , its throwing an error saying -

```
com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.SqlException: Connection authorization failure occurred.  Reason: security mechanism not supported
```

Can anyone tell, how to handle/configure Squirrel SQL Client to make this URL working ?

Comment: Seems like there is an authorization problem, username correct? password correct? authentication mechanism correct? Try a direct authentication  with the db2 driver: java com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Jcc -url jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/sample -user db2inst1 -password mypass

Comment: My url pattern is like jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/sample:authenticateMechanism=13 and username and password is correct.if i remove authenticateMechanism=13 frm url then it throws above expection and if i add it then it will throw Invalid Url Exception.

Comment: is there a colon or semi colon before the authenticateMechanim parameter?

Comment: Also, I do not see the authenticateMechanism as a valid parameter, but securityMechanism: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.1.0/com.ibm.db2.udb.apdv.java.doc/doc/rjvdsprp.htm

Comment: Yup its a securityMechanism=13, and its separated with colon. Edited my post

Comment: Which documentation explains the securityMechanism argument?

Comment: Actually its property which we need to put when connecting with DB.

Comment: AFAIK these parameters are only for DB2, and you cannot specify more parameters. Only, if you are developing your own driver which implements the JDBC protocol.

Comment: Ok, thats correct but when i am trying to connect with java code using Properties and add these property securityMechanism=13 , its working fine, so my question is how and where i have to configure these property in Squirrel so that i can able to connect with DB2..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. To solve it you need to add two properties to your SQuirreL Alias, securityMechanism=13 and encryptionAlgorithm=2. It worked in my case hope it will help for you:)
Adding some Screenshots:
[Alias properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukuxZ.png)
[Driver properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUMQ3.png)