# Db2 Connection in Squirrel or Dbeaver

Tags: jdbc, db2, squirrel-sql, dbeaver

iam trying to connect with Db2 using Squirrel/ Dbeaver and my url contains securityMechanism=13 at the end.
I am getting an excpetion ..

```
com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.SqlException: SqlException: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException is caught when initializing EncryptionManager 'Prime size must be multiple of 64, and can only range from 512 to 4096 (inclusive)'
```

Did anyone faces this issue ? How to resolve it ?

i am using sqljdbc4.jar and db2jcc.jar for same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configure authenticate Mechanism in Squirrel SQL Client for DB2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32988133/configure-authenticate-mechanism-in-squirrel-sql-client-for-db2)

Comment: Yes it is, didn't got the solution so i created again with some more details